# How do I prevent my website from being shown as a "referrer site" under the incoming links of a site I linked to?

Tags: internet

Okay, so I have websites and Wordpress blogs that link to a lot of useful sites - like professor webpages and other wordpress blogs. However, I don't want them to know of my sites or wordpress blogs. Is there a way to prevent them from being able to see them if they check the incoming links of their site? Would robots.txt work?

Comment: Oh, I just thought of an idea. Would putting the link through bit.ly or tinyURL work?

Comment: yes, using a URL shortener should do the trick. Keep in mind that for some URL shorteners though, such as [goo.gl](http://goo.gl/info/KQXDx#week), _anybody_ can see statistics for a shortened URL, which may include referrer information.

Comment: The HTTP-Referer field is set and transmitted by the browser.  `robots.txt` is for browser or cralwer consumption, but compliance with it is voluntary and `robots.txt` makes no provision for telling a browser not to transmit the HTTP-Referer header.  Even if that was possible, it's a bad idea to rely on that as you're depending on the browser to obey that, but there's no way you can really force it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'd have to use an anonymizer such as [anonym.to](http://anonym.to/).

Comment: Oh, how does that differ from a place like bit.ly or tinyURL?

Comment: URL shorteners are in the market of shortening the URL; `http://www.example.com/wow/this/is/a/long/url?isnt#it` shortens to, say, `http://bit.ly/123`. Anonymizers are only there to sit in the middle; the resultant would be similar to `http://anonym.to/?http://www.example.com/wow/this/is/a/long/url%3fisnt%23it`.

Answer (score -1):

Ghostery: http://www.ghostery.com/download is a great solution for blocking all or just some tracking scripts on the web. It's highly configurable. I've not tested it out as I heard about it yesterday but it seems to do what you'd like.

Comment: How does this help the person that runs the website?

Comment: I'm sorry. I misread. The only way to block people from getting to your sites or blogs would be to block the people you don't want via IP range using .htaccess